.Net Maui Community Toolkit Popup Multiple pages
I'm making a login process in a .Net Maui shell based app and thought it'd be good to do it in a popup (either community toolkit or mopup but there's an open issue putting me off mopup at the moment).
I want to break up the login process so we have different pages for the basic credentials, session details which are basically supplimentary login details, potential login error handling or password reset, so that's about 4 pages and as a popup I can have a static page behind it and the content of the popup navigating to different states instead of the whole page transitioning (on Android this wouldnt be too bad but targetting Windows too).
In the past (Xamarin) I've done that all in one and handled transitions between them myself but I want to "do the right thing" and they feel like separate pages I should be using shell navigation for and outside of the popup but is this possible inside a popup?
Reaching out because I've looked around a lot and cant find where to begin trying anything.  Any pointer would be appreciated (or "no you can't, stop trying") and I'll go off and work on it and add information back to help others.

you can popup a navigationpage that contains the various login pages, or you could just use a single contentpage that uses multiple ContentViews

Thanks @Jason  NavigationPage has to be a root element and popup doesn't allow it as content.  Looks like I will have to fake it with different views and animate between them inside the popup myself.
Shame, would be nice to have a separate stack of pages to navigate between inside the popup with animation and handling consistent with the wider app.

Popup of Community Toolkit is indeed no navigation mechanism. Use the Close() and Show() methods to switch between pop-ups？

@JianweiSun-MSFT That might work because the community toolkit popups don't offer any animation when they're shown but as I wanted that animation, I ended up faced with the Mopup popups project or rolling my own.  I ended up doing the latter.  It's not really an answer but I will post an answer so that people can see it.

By way of closing this off I'm posting this answer as I've followed @Jason 's advice.
There would be a lot of code to post but the bulk comes from a blog post I found about how to build and present your own popups with customisable animation (https://redth.codes/popups-with-net-maui-no-plugin-nuget-needed) and used that to make my own system.
With separate pages as content views all added but not always visible in a grid element representing the popup itself (set to clip to bounds) I was able to animate one page to move leftwards and the next to come in from the right as needed.
Once that was working I made it "proper", moving the popup appear/disappear logic logic to a base class and introduced view models so that the view reacts to changes in state (current page enum) and fires commands back to the VM from code behind and buttons/entries etc.
I don't know if I'm allowed (it's a work project), or will have time but if I ever write it up I'll return here and link to the write up, it's not far off being yet another nice popup library.
